# Counter in separate text file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a script that processes files based on drop folders, I created a function to do the processing and based on a set of variables I process a folder

```
funtion filedetect {
//
<some processing code code>
//
}

folder=1
source="/dir_1/"
reciep="me@mo.ma"
filedetect    

folder=2
source="/dir_2"
reciep="ma@me.mo"
filedetect
```

Now I would like to add a piece of code to create 1 text file with a counter that basically counts how many files are found and processed in each folder.
That is why I added the variable 'folder' so that the text file contains something like:

```
FOLDER 1 = [count]
FOLDER 2 = [count]
etc.
```

But for that I need to read by line the previous 'count' and replace that with count=count+1

How do I read the correct line based on the text file?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've started with something like this

```
folder1=10
folder2=4
folder3=7
```

You can write it out with a command such as this

```
set | grep -E '^folder[0-9]+=' > counter.txt
```

To read it back in again you can simply source the file

```
source counter.txt
```

If you have a shell that handles arrays (`bash`, `zsh`) you can index the set of folders to an arbitrarily large number

```
folder[1]=10
folder[2]=4
folder[3]=7
```

And write this one variable array out with

```
set | grep '^folder=' > counter.txt
```

Read it back in using `source`, as above.

For arrays you would reference them like this `echo "${folder[1]}"` or `foreach f "${folder[@]}"; do ... done`. Or even this if your index values are in strict ascending order from 1:

```
i=1
while [[ $i -le ${#folder[*]} ]]
do
    echo "$i => ${folder[$i]}"
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: This I will try to add into the script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file in YAML format, like

```
folder1: 10
folder2: 20
folder3: 30
```

You may use `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ to increment the count associated with folder `n` by one using

```bsh
yq -i -y --arg n 3 '.["folder"+$n] += 1' counts.txt
```

or, using more descriptive long options,

```bsh
yq --in-place --yaml-output --arg n 3 '.["folder"+$n] += 1' counts.txt
```

To get the current count associated with folder `n`:

```bsh
yq --arg n 3 '.["folder"+$n]' counts.txt
```